# Replace a string using the same word from other file

Tags: text-processing, sed, replace

I'm looking to edit my `1.txt` file, to find a word and replace it with the corresponding word in `2.txt` and also add the rest of the string of `2.txt`.

I'm interested in maintaining the order of my `1.txt` file.

```
>title1
ID1 .... rest of string I'm not interested in
>title2
ID2 .... rest of string I'm not interested in
>title3
ID3 .... rest of string I'm not interested in
>title....
```

But I want to add the information of my `2.txt`.

```
>ID1  text I want to extract
>ID2  text I want to extract
>ID3  text I want to extract
>IDs....
```

At the end, I'm looking to create a new file with this structure:

```
>title1
ID1 .... text I want
>title2
ID2 .... text I want
>title3
ID3 .... text I want
>title....
```

I have tried several sed commands, but most of them dont replace the ID# exactly for the one
that is in the two files. Hopefully it could be done in bash

Thanks for your help

Failed atempts..
my codes are
File 1 = cog_anotations.txt, File 2=Real.cog.txt
ID= COG05764, COG 015668, etc...

```
sed -e '/COG/{r Real.cog.txt' -e 'd}' cog_anotations.txt
sed "s/^.*COG.*$/$(cat Real.cog.txt)/" cog_anotations.txt
sed -e '/\$COG\$/{r Real.cog.txt'  -e 'd}' cog_anotations.txt
grep -F -f cog_anotations.txt Real.cog.txt > newfile.txt
grep -F -f Real.cog.txt cog_anotations.txt > newfile.txt
```

Real lines file 1

```
>Bravo_5
>CDD:223731 COG0658, ComEC, Predicted membrane metalbinding protein l 
>Bravo_6
>CDD:223242 COG0164, RnhB, Ribonuclease HII [DNA replication, 
>Bravo_7
>CDD:223778 COG0706, YidC, Preprotein translocase subunit YidC .
```

Real lines file 2

```
COG0006    E    Xaa-Pro aminopeptidase
COG0706    J    Glutamyl- or glutaminyl-tRNA synthetase
COG0164    J    tRNA A37 threonylcarbamoyladenosine synthetase subunit 
COG0012    J    Ribosome-binding ATPase YchF, GTP1/OBG family
COG0013    J    Alanyl-tRNA synthetase
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us some _real_ lines from your files. You are using `COG` in your `sed` commands but that doesn't exist in your files. The details will always depend on your exact data, so we need to see what you have in order to help you.

Comment: Crossposted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329003/replace-a-word-using-different-files-bash#62329003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{id[$1","]=$0}
  NR!=FNR{f=$0; getline; if (id[$2]) print f RS id[$2]}' file2 file1

>Bravo_6
COG0164    J    tRNA A37 threonylcarbamoyladenosine synthetase subunit 
>Bravo_7
COG0706    J    Glutamyl- or glutaminyl-tRNA synthetase
```

**Walkthrough**

Load an array with the `id` from the desired text in `file2` adding `,` to match with the other file

```
awk 'NR==FNR{id[$1","]=$0}
```

In the second file `NR!=FNR` Grab the first line in `f` and jump to the second `getline`

```
  NR!=FNR{f=$0; getline;
```

Then test to see if the `id` exists in your wanted array `(id[$2])` and print if it does

```
  if (id[$2]) print f RS id[$2]}' file2 file1
```